# How to execute a Bash script into a mysql docker container every time it starts

Tags: mysql, bash, docker, docker-compose

I need to execute these commands on every startup since it looks to be overwritten every time I set and restart it

```sh
mysql -uroot -padmin;
set global general_log = 1;
```

I start the docker container with docker-compose for development purposes only and it looks like this.

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  mysql_service:
    container_name: db_container
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./db/Dockerfile.dev
    # needed for mysql 8+
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    hostname: db
    ports:
      - target: 3306
        published: 3306
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=example
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=localhost
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - ./db/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      - data_volume:/var/lib/mysql/
    cap_add:
      - ALL
      
volumes:
  data_volume:
    driver: local
```

and the Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:8.0

COPY ./DevOps/Docker/db/set_logging.sh /usr/local/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh", "./usr/local/bin/set_logging.sh"]
```

However the copy goes through but the script is never executed.
Where the script looks like

```sh
#!/bin/bash
mysql -uroot -padmin -e "set global general_log = 1"
```

Any suggestions on getting this command to go through? This is only for development

Comment: Not the only option but the easiest here. Drop all of what you've done to try to fix this and simply add `--general-log=1` to your service command in your docker-compose file. To see a list of all config option you can set on the docker command line for mysql:8.0 without having to push a custom config to your container: `docker run -it --rm mysql:8.0 --verbose --help`. The [official mysql docker image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) has much more info on how to customize your container for various use cases.

Comment: Oh man I didn't know you could have multiple commands on the `- command` section of a docker-compose file.

Answer (score 1):

In order to tell MYSQL container to run that script once it starts you can either mount the script into the image's **/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d** folder using docker file, or docker-compose file using bind mount volume.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql:8.0
COPY ./DevOps/Docker/db/script.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/script.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-compose**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mysql_service:
    container_name: db_container
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./db/Dockerfile.dev
    # needed for mysql 8+
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    hostname: db
    ports:
      - target: 3306
        published: 3306
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=example
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=localhost
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - "./DevOps/Docker/db/script.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/script.sh"  
      - data_volume:/var/lib/mysql/
    cap_add:
      - ALL
      
volumes:
  data_volume:
    driver: local
```

You can check how scripts are launched in **/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d** read the [Initializing a fresh instance](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) Section

Comment: I have tried having `set global general_log = 1;` in the `initdb.d` script and that doesn't work. I have in that file all the initialization of my DB. This answer is also something already implemented in my code as you can see.